# Apply the Cauchy–Goursat theorem to compute the integral $\oint_C\frac{\sinh(z)}{z^{4}(1-z^{2})} dz$ where $C$ is the circle $|z|=2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Apply the Cauchy–Goursat theorem to compute the integral
$$
\oint_C\frac{\sinh(z)}{z^{4}(1-z^{2})}dz,
$$
where $C$ is the circle $|z|=2$.
Solution:
$z^{4}(1-z^{2})=0 \Rightarrow$
$z=0,z=±1$
points where the funtion is not analytic.

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{1}{{z^4 (1 - z^2 )}} = \frac{1}{{z^2 }} + \frac{1}{{z^4 }} - \frac{1}{{2(z - 1)}} + \frac{1}{{2(z + 1)}}.
$$

Comment: How can I communicate with you?

Comment: If yomething is not clear, write your question here in the comments. If you put @Gary in your comment, I will be notified.

Comment: @ItzyNajera I have posted an answer. You have to apply Cauchy Residue Theorem in order to compute the integral as the function has singularities inside the region. Cauchy Goursat simply states that if a function is analyitic in a simply connected domain then the contour integral is zero. But here the function is not analytic. You have to apply Cauchy Residue theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the residue at $0$ ,$1$ and $-1$.

For the residue at $0$ you need to calculate the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in the Laurent Series expansion around $0$.

To do that use :-

$\sinh(z)=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}=z+\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\frac{z^{5}}{5!}+....$.

And $\frac{1}{1-z^{2}}=1+z^{2}+z^{4}+z^{6}+....$

Combining them you need to find coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ in:-

$$\frac{1}{z^{4}}(z+\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\frac{z^{5}}{5!}+....)(1+z^{2}+z^{4}+z^{6}+....)=(z+\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\frac{z^{5}}{5!}+....)(\frac{1}{z^{4}}+\frac{1}{z^{2}}+1+z^{2}+...)$$.

Clearly the coefficient is $\frac{1}{3!}+1=\frac{7}{6}$.

Now for the residues at $1$ and $-1$. You see that

$\displaystyle\frac{\frac{\sinh(z)}{z^{4}(1-z)}}{1+z}$ has a simple pole at $z=-1$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\frac{-\sinh(z)}{z^{4}(1+z)}}{z-1}$ has a simple pole at $z=1$. So their residies are respectively $\frac{\sinh(-1)}{2}$ and $\frac{-\sinh(1)}{2}$ .

So the value of the integral by Cauchy Residue Theorem is :-

$$2i\pi\left(\frac{7}{6}-\sinh(1)\right)$$

Comment: 1/5! Is missing in the coefficient of 1/ z

Comment: @LawrenceMano . I don't  think anything is missing. Wolfram alpha also verifies that the residue is $\frac{7}{6}$. Kindly check your calculation again

Comment: If you decompose the fraction like I suggested in the comments, it is enough to know the Cauchy formula for $f^{(n)}(z)$.

Comment: And how do i get coefficient?

Comment: @ItzyNajera . If you see that $(z+\frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\frac{z^{5}}{5!}+....)(\frac{1}{z^{4}}+\frac{1}{z^{2}}+1+z^{2}+...)$. Then you get the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ if you multiply the $z$ term of the first bracket with $\frac{1}{z^{2}}$ and the $z^{3}$ term in the first bracket with $\frac{1}{z^{4}}$. It's just basic multiplication. You multiply out each term and see when does $\frac{1}{z}$ occur. And you neglect the higher order or unnecessary terms.

Answer (score 1):

$f(z)$ has an pole of order 4 in $z=0$ and the poles $z_{1,2}=\pm1$ all inside of the circle $|z|=2$, so
$$\int_{|z|=2}f(z)=2\pi i \sum{Res(f(z),z_i)}=2\pi i(Res(f(z),0)+Res(f(z),1)+Res(f(z),-1))$$